# Office Word JS - Get paragraph items within only the selected table cells

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I am working on an add-in for Word using Office JS. I have an issue getting the current selected paragraphs items within a Table selection, with a subset of table cells selected. The API only returns the paragraph items of the **last** selected Table Row.

I would like to get only the specific paragraphs within the currently selected cells.

[image]

If the selection is preceded or proceeded with another element, eg. empty paragraph. All paragraphs are returned.

[image]

This can be seen by loading paragraphs in selection.

```
  const range = context.document.getSelection();
  const paragraphs = range.paragraphs;

  range.load('paragraphs');
  paragraphs.load();

  await context.sync();

  console.log('Paragraphs', paragraphs.items);
```

Is there any workaround to this issue?